# Samco API dictionary issue

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
msg = {"response":{"data":{"aPr":"143.90","aSz":"75","avgPr":"190.12","bPr":"143.70","bSz":"75","c":"398.40","ch":"-254.50","chPer":"-63.88","h":"277.60","l":"123.20","lTrdT":"14 May 2020, 03:21:21 PM","ltp":"143.90","ltq":"75","ltt":"14 May 2020, 03:21:21 PM","lttUTC":"14 May 2020, 09:51:21 AM","o":"245.95","oI":"58275","oIChg":"-50100.00","sym":"59605_NFO","tBQ":"347625","tSQ":"44925","ttv":"425688175.07","vol":"2239050","yH":"277.60","yL":"0.00"},"streaming_type":"quote"}}
```

I would like to extract key values from this. I am using this code:

```
ltp = msg(["ltp"])
```

but it is showing:

```
error :string indices must be integers"
```

```
import requests
import pdb
import json
import pprint
import websocket
from websocket import WebSocketApp
import xlwings as xw
import datetime


name = "Tickdata"

wb = xw.Book('watchlist.xlsx')
sht3 = wb.sheets['Tickdata']
row_no = 2



def on_message(ws, msg):
    global row_no
    pdb.set_trace()
    print (msg)
    ltp = msg(["ltp"])


    sht3.range('A' + str(row_no)).value = msg
    row_no = row_no + 1

def on_error(ws, error):
    print (error)

def on_close(ws):
    print ("Connection Closed")

def on_open(ws):
    print ("Sending json")
    data='{"request":{"streaming_type":"quote", "data":{"symbols":[{"symbol":"59605_NFO"}, {"symbol":"59606_NFO"}]}, "request_type":"subscribe", "response_format":"json"}}'
    ws.send(data)
    ws.send("\n")


headers = {'x-session-token': ''}

websocket.enableTrace(True)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://stream.stocknote.com", on_open = on_open, on_message = on_message, on_error = on_error, on_close = on_close, header = headers)

ws.run_forever()
```

This is API of Samco "https://developers.stocknote.com/api/?python#search-equity-scrips".

Comment: `msg['response']['data']['ltp']`?

Comment: I get a different error with your code. Please show us the code that produces the problem!

Comment: If I run your code, this error message is not arising, because you have a dictionary`msg` but call it like a function `msg(['ltp']).` Which results in the following error: `'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: Code Pope: You are correct. I am also getting same result. I even tried options such as value = msg['response']['data']['ltp']. But it is showing same error: "string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below:

```
msg = {"response":{"data":{"aPr":"143.90","aSz":"75","avgPr":"190.12","bPr":"143.70","bSz":"75","c":"398.40","ch":"-254.50","chPer":"-63.88","h":"277.60","l":"123.20","lTrdT":"14 May 2020, 03:21:21 PM","ltp":"143.90","ltq":"75","ltt":"14 May 2020, 03:21:21 PM","lttUTC":"14 May 2020, 09:51:21 AM","o":"245.95","oI":"58275","oIChg":"-50100.00","sym":"59605_NFO","tBQ":"347625","tSQ":"44925","ttv":"425688175.07","vol":"2239050","yH":"277.60","yL":"0.00"},"streaming_type":"quote"}}

d = msg['response']['data']
for key, value in d.items():
 print(key)
 print(value)
```

Or directly you can get key value:

```
value = msg['response']['data']['ltp']
```

Comment: Note this does not get the value of ltp, it rather prints all the values in the data dict. See my answer, as it shows a way of getting the ltp value OP wanted, and also shows how to turn it into a number

Comment: I tried this also. But same error: "string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 0):

You do not call a dictionary. As user @fas in comments pointed out, ltp is not inside the dictionary directly, it is nested inside the data dictionary, which is nested inside the response dictionary. So your code will be:

```py
ltp = msg["response"]["data"]["ltp"]
```

If you want it to be in a decimal, use

```py
ltp = float(msg["response"]["data"]["ltp"])
```

Comment: I tried this also. But same error: "string indices must be integers"

Comment: @RajeshRai are you getting it from a web request? If so you need to parse it. If you use requests then use the .json method of the response.  Like this:
msg = requests.get("url here").json()

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the dictionary level by level.

Having:

```
{'response': {'data': {'ltp': '143.90'}}}
```

You have three levels so doing:

```
msg['response']['data']['ltp']
```

Will give you the value. If you only want the key values, can use keys() like so:

```
msg['response']['data'].keys()
```

Comment: Will try this method. Then reply.

Comment: did not worked this. Showing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"